# SwitchCompat always displays false On Create even though checked is true in xml

Tags: java, android, switchcompat

How come my `switchCompat`'s checked state = true (as declared in xml). But when It is viewed at Oncreate in java, it displays as false?

Is there another way to set the switchCompat's state?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:checked="true"
        android:id="@+id/translationonnoff"
        android:theme="@style/SCBSwitch"       
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Could you also include you onCreate method. Also, have you tried changing it to `android:checked="false"` to see if it would make any difference, because you might have forgotten to setContentView to the proper xml file.

Comment: Including my `onCreate` Method wouldn't make a difference in my question because there is nothing in it. However, The activity is a Fragment if that matters. And yes, I tried that. @A.Pahlavan

Comment: Well I doubt your using the right switchCompat. Do double check the id when you're doing `findViewById`. Also you need to include `app:showText="false"` otherwise you will get errors, and that's another reason why I belive you're not using the correct id.

Comment: Your misunderstanding my question. In my xml, checked is declared as true. But when I run my app, The state (value) of the `switchCompat` DISPLAYS false. Even though, it is declared as true. @A.Pahlavan

Comment: I tested myself and it run what i was  expected. Show your `onCreate`code please.

Comment: My `OnCreate` Code is empty @TruongHieu

Comment: Could it have to do with my style or my xml? @TruongHieu

Comment: Actually, I noticed it works perfectly in an Activity, but the problem lies within a fragment @TruongHieu

Comment: So you solved it?

Comment: No, my problem still lies within the fragment. @TruongHieu

Comment: I tested on my fragment, still ok. Do you write anything in that file?
Or  you can remove SwitchCompat ID then retest it